# How to get total number of products quantity on order success page in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to get the quantity of total number of product ordered.
How to implement it in Magento 1?

Comment: Do you find the solution? Does any of the below answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Magento order success page, you will able to get the Order Increment Id using code `$this->getOrderId()`. Then you can load the order by Increment Id
and get all the Items`($order->getAllItems())`. Please try the below code to achieve your requirement.

```
$orderId = $this->getOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$items = $order->getAllItems();
or 
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach($items as $item) {
   $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered();           
}
```

For total orderded Qty try below:

```
$order->getTotalItemCount();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code:

```
$order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId()); //increment_id
$ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($ordered_items as $item){
    echo $item->getQtyOrdered();  //ordered qty of item
}
```

for getting total qty of an order,use this code.

```
$order->getData('total_qty_ordered');
```

Hope this solution will help you!

Happy Coding!